# Round-off values in a GridView cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and it is programmatically bound a to a `List<T>` where T is a custom object of mine, say, `OrderItem`. The decimal type values display many decimal places. I want to round them off to just 2 decimal places. How do I do that?

Here's roughly what I have:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal GrossAmount { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountPercent { get; set; }
}



    <asp:GridView ID="dgOrderItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false">

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Product">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Product.ProductName") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Product.Price") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Quantity" HeaderText = "Quantity" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField = "GrossAmount" HeaderText = "Gross Amount" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Discount (%)">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Product.DiscountPercent") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>            
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the formatting available in Eval on TemplateFields, i.e.:

```
<%# Eval("Product.Price", "{0:C}") %>
```

For Bound Fields use the [BoundField.DataFormatString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx), i.e.:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="GrossAmount" 
                HeaderText="Gross Amount" 
                DataFormatString="{0:f2}" />
```

See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for the formatting strings you can use.

Comment: And what do I do for the simple BoundField definitions that do not use the Eval function?